# google mapapi key works on one android application but not on another

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview

I have 2 android apps both are signe with the same certificate, both are using the same google mapapi key created for the certificate. how come only one of the application is showing maps???

Comment: Do they both have internet connectivity?

Comment: @Falmarri both have conectivity

Comment: That's the only reason I can think that this would happen. Or you didn't sign them with the same certificate like you think you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so stupid!!!

I had 2 places that used the same api key an i updated only one of them... next time it goes into the string.xml file...